# use material UI makeStyles with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design, typescript-typings

I have created a separate file for `classes` prop for e.g. `MuiAlert`

What is the way to tell `makeStyles` that you are only allowed to use Alert classes?

The following works but I am sure there must be a better way. So e.g. If I rename `root` to `roott`, I will get error that `'roott' does not exist in type 'Partial<Record<AlertClassKey, any>>'`

Playground example: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-material-ui-3t7ln?file=/src/index.ts

```js
import { Theme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { AlertClassKey } from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";

export const useAlertClasses = makeStyles<Theme>(
  (): Partial<Record<AlertClassKey, any>> => ({
    root: {
      borderRadius: 3,
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
import { Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";
import { StyleRules } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { AlertClassKey } from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";

export const alertOverrides = (
    theme: Theme
): Partial<StyleRules<AlertClassKey>> => {
    return {
        root: {
            backgroundColor: "red !important",
        },
    };
};

export const useAlertStyles = makeStyles<Theme, {}>(
    (theme) => {
        return createStyles(alertOverrides(theme) as never);
    },
    { name: "MuiAlert" }
);
```